# Doing an INSERT ALL using JDBC in ORACLE

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition

I want to insert records into 2 tables say TABLE1 and TABLE2 back to back using JDBC. These 2 tables have a primary key and foreign key relationship based on a common column say ID_COLUMN

I am planing to use the following single query and fire it via my Java application via JDBC:

```
insert all 
  into TABLE1 (ID_COLUMN,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)
  into TABLE2 (COL1_1,COL_1_2,COL_1_3,ID_COLUMN) values('blah',42,'rubbish', 
   select test_ctrl.seq_test_id.nextval FROM dual) 
  select * from dual;
```

My basic requirement is that I need to INSERT TABLE2 with the latest ID_COLUMN from TABLE1 from my current session.
I know the usage of `select test_ctrl.seq_test_id.nextval FROM dual` in the INSERT ALL statement is not correct. But it being Oracle I cant use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Please suggest how can I make this query work

Comment: ...since you are on oracle (and bare jdbc), a PL/SQL could (easily) wrap this (insert all) and store the id (in a variable)....

Answer (score 0):

> "But it being Oracle I cant use SCOPE_IDENTITY()"

Ah but you can. In Oracle 12c they introduced identity columns: these are a special variant of virtual columns.

```
create table my_table (
    id number generated always as identity 
    ....
    , constraint my_table_pk primary key (id)
```

[Find out more.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAHJHJC)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found out the answer to my question.Modified the query like this.Please take note of edme_ctrl.seq_ts_annotation_id.nextval and edme_ctrl.seq_ts_annotation_id.currval

```
INSERT ALL INTO "SPI7CG_CgNvI".X$ANNOTATIONS(ANNOTATION_ID,CATEGORY,REASON,COMMENTS,AUTHOR,ADJUSTMENT_TYPE,ADJUSTMENT_VALUE) VALUES (edme_ctrl.seq_ts_annotation_id.nextval, '51','33','Test Bulk Insert','kshiam','A',10) INTO "SPI7CG_CgNvI".X$DATA_ANNOTATIONS(ANNOTATION_ID, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROW_ID,COLUMN_NAME) VALUES (edme_ctrl.seq_ts_annotation_id.currval,'W$XXXXXGNVBSNSSNDCTRSSR007',164921155,'IVXXXXXGNVBXWGSQDTWQRTR0003') select * from dual
```